# nvidia driver is not loading after kernel update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I downloaded Nvidia driver from Nvidia's website. I set up it under kernel 3.11.0-17. Every thing was almost perfect for me. It was even working after update to kernel 3.11.0-18. However I wanted to clear the old kernel, so I uninstalled kernel 3.11.0.17.

Ubuntu just went to command line after boot screen, then I typed `sudo depmod -a`, after rebooting things are back. However, command line screen came again at the next restart. So now I need to keep calling `sudo depmod -a` and restarting again and again. How do I get over this?

Comment: You might want to add more information, like the Ubuntu version you're using and the exact driver you downloaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)